# Relative Path Problem for Glob's Ignore option in Node script

Tags: node.js

I have this project structure:

```
.
├── index.js
└── bootstrap/
    ├── css/
    │   ├── style.css
    │   └── fake.js
    └── js/
        └── index.js
```

I am trying to find all the **JS** files under **bootstrap** folder ignoring the **css** folder. I use glob code below:

**index.js**

```
const { globSync } = require('glob');

const files = globSync([`./bootstrap/**/*.js`], {
  ignore: [`bootstrap/css/**`],
});

files.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file); // outputs bootstrap/js/index.js
})
```

It works as expected and only JS files under bootsrap/js directory are retrieved because of the **ignore** property.

But if I change ignore property to relative path

```
ignore: [`./bootstrap/css/**`],
```

it does not exclude css folder any more:

```
const { globSync } = require('glob');

const files = globSync([`./bootstrap/**/*.js`], {
  ignore: [`./bootstrap/css/**`],
});

files.forEach(file => {
  console.log(file); // outputs bootstrap/js/index.js and bootstrap/css/fake.js
})
```

What is the problem here? Why can not I use relative path for ignore property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `glob` package feels outdated and could work not as expected with new versions of node. The newer code uses `fast-glob` which works with both `ignore` and negation patterns:

```
import glob from 'fast-glob';

const files = await glob([`./bootstrap/**/*.js`], {
  ignore: [`./bootstrap/css/**`],
});

console.log('ignore:', files);

const filesByNegation = await glob([`./bootstrap/**/*.js`, `!./bootstrap/css/**`]);

console.log('negation:', filesByNegation);
```

https://replit.com/@silentmantra/Glob-Test#index.js

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your negation character version but it does not fix it. You can test it here. https://replit.com/@ctrall/Glob-Test It seems as you suggested I can not use relative paths in ignore

Comment: Much appreciated for your help, it works flawless.